# Excel - Adding multiple columns after last column in chart

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro in Excel that will add three columns to the end of the chart, identical to the previous columns found in the chart with one of the columns increasing by one.

For example:

```
Column 1         Column 2   Column 3    Column 4         Column 5   Column 6
PGM Number 1     Amount     Notes       PGM Number 2     Amount     Notes
```

Is there a way to add three columns (PGM Number +1, Amount and Notes) at the end of the chart, so it can do the following?

```
Column 7      Column 8   Column 9       Column 10      Column 11   Column 12
PGM Number 3     Amount     Notes       PGM Number 4      Amount       Notes
```

This is the code I have to replicate the last column:

```
Sub InsertColumn()
Dim lastColumn As Long
lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
Columns(lastColumn).Copy Destination:=Columns(lastColumn + 1)
End Sub
```

But obviously this is not enough.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub addCols()

Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim f As String
Dim s As String
Dim t As String
Dim c As Long

f = "PGM Number "
s = "Amount"
t = "Notes"

With ActiveSheet

    lastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    c = (lastColumn + 3) / 3

    'assuming first row, otherwise change "1" to desired row
    .Cells(1, lastColumn + 1) = f & c
    .Cells(1, lastColumn + 2) = s
    .Cells(1, lastColumn + 3) = t

End With

End Sub
```